# Find Dot Separated Words in a String

Tags: regex, logging, sas, string-parsing

I need to parse a log file to pick out strings that match the following case-insensitive pattern:

```
libname.data   <--- Okay
libname.*      <--- Not okay
```

For those with SAS experience, I'm trying to get SAS dataset names out of a large log.

All strings are space-separated. Some examples of lines:

```
NOTE: The data set LIBNAME.DATA has 428 observations and 15 variables.
MPRINT(MYMACRO):   data libname.data;
MPRINT(MYMACRO):   create table libname.data(rename=(var1 = var2)) as select distinct var1, var2 as
MPRINT(MYMACRO):   format=date. from libname.data where ^missing(var1) and ^missing(var2) and
```

## What I've tried

This PERL regular expression:

`/^(?!.*[.*]{2})[a-z0-9*_:-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9;_:-]+)+$/mi`

https://regex101.com/r/jYkXn5/1

In SAS code:

```
data test;
    line = 'words and stuff libname.data';
    test = prxmatch('/^(?!.*[.*]{2})[a-z0-9*_:-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9;_:-]+)+$/mi', line);
run;
```

## Problem

This will work when the line only contains this exact string, but it will not work if the line contains other strings.

## Solution

Thanks, Blindy!

The regex that worked for me to parse SAS datasets from a log is:

`/(?!.*[.*]{3})[a-z_]+[a-z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-z0-9_]+)/mi`

```
data test;
    line = 'NOTE: COMPRESSING DATA SET LIBNAME.DATA DECREASED SIZE BY 46.44 PERCENT';

    prxID = prxparse('/(?!.*[.*]{3})[a-z]+[a-z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-z0-9_]+)/mi');
    call prxsubstr(prxID, line, position, length);

    dataset = substr(line, position, length);
run;
```

This will still pick up some SQL select statements but that is easily solvable through post-processing.

Comment: Remove the `^` anchor

Comment: If you are scanning logs then just check for the NOTE: lines.  The dataset names will be uppercase only there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You anchored your expression at the beginning, simply remove the first `^` and you're set.

```
/(?!.*[.*]{2})[a-z0-9*_:-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9;_:-]+)+$/mi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get by just locating the following landmark text in a log file line.

```
... data set <LIBNAME>.<MEMNAME> ...
```

If the data set name is in the log you can presume it was correctly formed.

```
data want;
  length line $1000;
  infile LOG_FILE lrecl=1000 length=L;
  
  input line $VARYING. L;

  * literally "data set <name>" followed by space or period;
  rx = prxparse('/data set (.*?)\.(.*?)[. ]/');

  if prxmatch(rx,line) then do;
    length libname $8 memname $32;
    libname = prxposn(rx,1,line);
    memname = prxposn(rx,2,line);
    line_number = _n_;
    output;
  end;

  keep libname memname line_number;
run;
```

Some adjustment would be needed if the data set names are name literals of the form `'<anything>'N`

There are also a plethora of existing SAS Log file parsers and analyzers out on the web that you can utilize.

Answer (score 0):

The lookahead at the start prevents matching `..` but the pattern by itself will not match that, as the character classes are repeated 1 or more times and do not contain a dot.

If you don't want to match `**` as well, and the string should not start with `*`, you can add that to a character class `[*.]` together with the dot, and take it out of the first character class.

In that case, you could omit the positive lookahead and the anchor:

```
/[a-z0-9_:-]+(?:[.*][a-z0-9_:-]+)+/i
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i5nukH/1)

As the pattern does not contain any anchors, you could omit the `m` flag.